# Trouble Implementing a Linked List from Scratch (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was working on a Linked List implementation from scratch. I was recently graded on this assignment and the professor marked my **removeFirst()** method as wrong. This method is tasked with removing the first element in a linked list, and I think I accomplished this as proven by my console. I'm unable to contact my professor and am wondering why my implementation of the **removeFirst()** method is wrong. How should I implement this method?

Here is the implementation attempt:

```
public class LinkedList{ 
    //Embedded node class
    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        //constructor for passing value to a created Node object
        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        //method will return node value
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private Node first;  //Also called "head"
    private Node last; //"Also called "tail"


    public void addLast(int item) {
        //wrap item in node
        Node node = new Node(item);
        //if linked list is empty, set first and last references to point to new node that has now been constructed
        if (isEmpty())
            first = last = node;
        else {
            //items in Linked List already exist.
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(int item) {
        //wrap item in node, pass value to Node constructor.
        Node node = new Node(item);
        //check if L.L is empty
        if (isEmpty()) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            //there are existing nodes in the L.L..
            //set newly constructed node as "first"
            node.next = first;
            first = node;
        }
    }

    //isEmpty method returns boolean judging if first == null; this implies empty.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public Node getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    //implementation.. 
    public void removeFirst() {    //<<<---- method in question 
        first = first.next; 
    }


    //main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        ll.addLast(3);
        ll.addLast(4);
        ll.addLast(9);
        ll.removeFirst(); 
        System.out.print(ll.getFirst().getValue()); 
        //outputs 4, which is the new head. Correct implementation? 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `removeFirst` supposed to do when the list is already empty? Your teacher will be looking at all cases, so also that case. Right now it throws an exception. Just make it conditional.

Comment: are you asked to return the item ie if there is nodes you return the node, so you can use the removed value for other things?

Comment: @trincot yes, I suppose you're right in that I should add a condition to filter through that edge case. However, after further research, there may be other problems with my implementation.  If we change what **first** is referring to, there is still a reference from what *was* the first node to the second node (which is now the first).. Is there any truth to that? It seems to be merely an opinion by someone on another thread.

Comment: About that other problem you speak of: no this is not a problem. Provided that you don't have other variables that still reference the removed first node, its *reference count* has become zero, and so it becomes a candidate for garbage collection. This is independent on whether that node still has a reference to another (second) object. That is irrelevant.